# Why is my Cronjob giving me this error?

Tags: python, cron, daemon

```
/bin/sh: /Users/alex/filename.py: No such file or directory
```

I have set a cronjob and it runs at the right time but the script isn't getting executed. When I check the mail I get that error. Both the script and the cronjob file are in:

```
/Users/alex
```

My cronjob file looks like this:

```
45 19 * * * /Users/alex/filename.py
```

I know the script works because I can launch it manually from the terminal.

Where am I screwing this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it `Users` and not `users`? Does your `filename.py` have execute permission for cron?

Comment: Macs have a "Users" directory. That's probably what it is.

Comment: I needed to change the permissions for the file

`chmod a+w filename.py` seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
45 19 * * * /path/to/python /Users/alex/filename.py
```

where `path/to/python` is something like `/usr/bin/python` (default on OS X I believe).

Comment: It's still giving me the
    
    /bin/sh: /path/to/python: No such file or directory

Comment: Doh. Of course.

Edited the path so that it is
    30 8 * * * /usr/bin/env python /users/alex/filename.py

And now get this

    python: can't open file '/users/alex/filename.py': [Errno 2] No   such file or directory

Comment: @AlexRamadan have you capitalized the U in Users?

Comment: @NolenRoyalty Yes

`25 21 * * * /usr/bin/env python /Users/alex/filename.py`